# Unexpected $end in PHP file

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP contact form, but I can't get it to work. I get the following error in the Apache server log, running on an Ubuntu Server VM:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/matthew/Sites/contactFormResponse.php on line 75, referer: http://192.168.1.4/contactForm.php
```

From googling this error, it sounds like it's normally caused by either using the short PHP tag when the server's not set up to recognise them, or by having a block of code that isn't closed correctly. But as far as I can see that isn't the case here - as far as I can see it's all closed correctly. The line it refers to is one line past the end of the file.

Here's the PHP code:

```
 <?php
                                    error_reporting(E_ALL);
                                    // Define variables to hold the name, email address and message, and import the information into the variables
                                    $name = $_POST['NameInput'];
                                    $email = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
                                    $telno = $_POST['ContactNumber'];
                                    $querytype = $_POST['QueryType'];
                                    $bookingstartdate = $_POST['BookingStartDay'] . $_POST['BookingStartMonth'] . $_POST['BookingStartYear'];
                                    $bookingenddate = $_POST['BookingEndDay'] . $_POST['BookingEndMonth'] . $_POST['BookingEndYear'];
                                    $message = $_POST['QueryText'];

                                    // Validate the inputs - send it if it's OK
                                    if(3 < strlen($name) && 3 < strlen($email))
                                    {
                                            $email_message = <<< EMAIL
                                                    Message from contact form at holidaychalet.co.uk
                                                    Name: $name
                                                    Email: $email
                                                    Contact Number: $telno
                                                    Query Type: $querytype
                                                    Booking Start Date: $bookingstartdate
                                                    Booking End Date: $bookingenddate
                                                    The message:
                                                    $message
                                                    EMAIL;
                                            $headers = "cc:me@myemailaddress.com\r\n";
                                            if(mail('matthew@localhost','Contact form email', $email_message, $headers))
                                            {
                                                    echo "Thanks for completing the form! I'll be in touch shortly!";
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                    echo "Something went wrong - please use the back button and try again";
                                            }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            echo "You didn't complete the form fully enough! Please use go back using your web browser's back button";
                                    }
                            ?>
```

Comment: These questions are against SO policy.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Why? I can't see anything about it in the FAQ and I couldn't find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: Your question isn't against a policy, I have no idea what Col. Shrapnel is talking about either.

Comment: it's too localized. The answer can help only you and nobody else.

Comment: Au contraire. The answer can help anyone using a heredoc and accidentally indenting the closing identifier. The title is one that would come up when searching on the common error message, and the answer is also widely applicable - this is a common mistake. Honestly, Col. Shrapnel, your crusade isn't very helpful.

Comment: For the record, I came here via Google and this solved my problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closing identifier for the [here document syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) must be at the start of the line without any indentation:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except ***possibly*** a semicolon (`;`). That means especially that the identifier ***may not be indented***, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system.

So in your case:

```
                                            $email_message = <<< EMAIL
                                                    Message from contact form at holidaychalet.co.uk
                                                    Name: $name
                                                    Email: $email
                                                    Contact Number: $telno
                                                    Query Type: $querytype
                                                    Booking Start Date: $bookingstartdate
                                                    Booking End Date: $bookingenddate
                                                    The message:
                                                    $message
EMAIL;
```

Comment: +1 Sadly, this is the way it is, rendering HEREDOC useless in most cases.

Comment: Er? It's still completely usable... having the close identifier not indented doesn't kill code readability. In fact, it makes sense, considering that the indent whitespace for the heredoc *contents* will be included in the string produced, thus it keeps the developer conscious of what they're putting in their strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
EMAIL;
```

cannot be indented. [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax requires that the closing identifier be at the *start* of the line, and that includes no leading whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

You are filling $email_message with a string which is marked to end with EMAIL;

This one must be in a single line.

Change it to:

```
                                            $email_message = <<< EMAIL
                                                    Message from contact form at holidaychalet.co.uk
                                                    Name: $name
                                                    Email: $email
                                                    Contact Number: $telno
                                                    Query Type: $querytype
                                                    Booking Start Date: $bookingstartdate
                                                    Booking End Date: $bookingenddate
                                                    The message:
                                                    $message
EMAIL;
```